В чём отличие formatter<const char*>, formatter<std::string_view> и formatter<std::string>?
В чём отличие форматтеров для строковых типов от которых можно наследоваться? Если их нет, то почему бы всегда не юзать первый, который не требует инклюдов? Сами форматтеры определены в core.h или format.h?
